# Random text/quote/fact every 24 hour! (Kinda like «Quote of the day»)

Tags: javascript, random

**Skip the bold text if you just care about the question.**

**I made a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119612/random-text-every-24-hour), but I didn't really understand the site so somehow did I manage to made a new user or something, and can't edit my question to make it more understandable. English isn't my first language, but I will try to make it more clear this time what my question is. Thanks for any answers that will try to help.**

OK, I want it so that a random text would be display every new day. Let’s perhaps say I have these texts:

- *She likes fish.*
- *He doesn't need to know.*
- *What to do?*
- *Maybe she'll try it.*

I want it so every day the text change it to something random. Kinda a «word of the day»-thing, but instead of me manually changing the text every day I just want it so it gets random by itself every day. How would I do this? I've tried to search a lot, but haven't found any way to do it how I want. The best way I found was a random-number-every-day, but that was with numbers, not text. This is like a automatic «Quote/Fact/Word of the day»-thing. I found quote of the day-sites too, but those was just generators and didn't let me pick the text. I want to pick them by my self (like write them, and then they come random every day).

Completely random. Doesn't matter if the same text gets two day in a row, I simply need it so that a random text up every day. So this pretty much sums it up: a random text/quote/fact every day. It would be great if this is in javascript. It doesn't matter if it’s not the same text for every user/computer, so one guy could have another text one day than another one (as I understand it doesn't go to make it the same quote/fact/text for every user the same with javascript).

Thanks for any help. I'm grateful for that! :-)

Comment: Alas, this question will be closed like your previous one if you do not post the code you tried to solve your problem. Stack Overflow is about helping you with your code, not writing it for you.

Comment: is this not exactly the same as your last question.. as someone linked you to before : http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: We don't program for you. Consider hiring a contract coder if you can't or won't learn it

Comment: Sounds like you want a freelancer

Comment: If it's only changing once a day for the whole site, doing it on the client side in javascript seems a bit silly.

Comment: I want to learn it, and can a little bit of javascript, but have really no clue how to do this. If someone just can help me how to do it at least.

Comment: @ChristofferHN I would recommend using a MySQL database containing all the information, and then have php retrieve 'todays fact' and display it in the HTML, no javascript is needed for this.

Comment: [Here are some useful free JS books](http://jsbooks.revolunet.com/).

Comment: @Christoffer, to put you on the right track: it appears you already know how to generate a random number (index), so if you store your strings in an array, then generate a random index and fetch that element...

Comment: Frederic: So basically I just need to replace the numbers with the text I want to be displayed?

Comment: @Christoffer, something like that. I'd suggest you get familiar with arrays, they're a basic building block in almost all languages.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try that, but if I don't get it working, would it be possible to make it so that people just can click a button or reload the page to display the random text? Like, random every time you reload the page or somenthing …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an array containing all your quotes
2. Create a random number based on the current date, which goes from 0 to n (n being the amount of quotes in your array - 1)
3. Show the item of the array which has the index of the random number created in step 2

Try to write code yourself, and if you have a specific problem somewhere, the community will be happy to help you. But as mentioned in the comments, noone is gonna do all the work for you, you have to show effort yourself.